# how to check if email is not verified Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, email

I thought like

```html
<?php
if (user->hasVerifiedEmail()){
        header('Location:somewhere');
    }
?>
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `$` sign. The correct syntax would be:

```
if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()){
        header('Location:somewhere');
    }
```

You need to initialize the $user variable before using

Comment: nah. that doesn't work either. error undefined constant

Comment: What do you get `dd($user->hasVerifiedEmail());`

Comment: aaah. I figured. ye, I forgot `require`